# what does "Error: one input ui-file must be specified" in pyqt5 mean? How can I solve it?

Tags: pyuic

### In pycharm settting, I add "external Tool" which name is pyUIC,  argument is "

### PyQt5.uic.pyuic
$FileName$

$FileNameWithoutExtension$.py"  ,programm is "G:\m_anaconda\envs\Mogcn\python.exe",
working directory is "$FileDir$"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after I change my file name from "Dailuge - mainPage.ui" to "mainPage.ui".
everything become success !